# how many subscribe devices are allowed to a single Topic in firebase cloud messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app News page visited user devices are subscribe to the Topic: "MYAPP_NEWS"
is there any limitation for subscribe to a Topic. if yes,  how many subscribe devices are  allowed to  a single Topic in firebase cloud messaging.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging):

> `Topic messaging supports unlimited topics and subscriptions for each app.`